# Java Collections to filter element using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, collections, filter, java-7

I am looking if there is a collection in java API, where I am able to retrieve the elements which are starting with some given text.

For example, If i have following elements in the collection

```
abc
abbb
adf
abab
dfg
cfg
```

if I type "a", then it should return all the elements starting with character "a".

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to include something like this in the collections API. It applies only to strings, and is a very specific requirement. This is the sort of thing you'll have to code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no collection that can give you this filtering out-of-the-box but you can do a simple pipeline (needs Java 8):

```
filteredList = collection.stream()
                         .filter(e -> e.startsWith("a"))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are third-party libraries that allow filtering collections as well:

- Guava's [`Collections2#filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)).
- [`ColectionUtils#filter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate)) from Apache Commons Collections.

The linked Javadoc descriptions explain exactly how each method does the filtering (i.e. whether it modifies the given collection, or it returns a new one).

---

Or simply using a `for` loop ([java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) and before):

```
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Iterator<String> iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String str = iterator.next();
    if(str.startsWith("a")) {
        filteredList.add(str);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @AR_3, thank you for the answer, This feature u have suggested is available in java 1.8, Using java 1.6 is there easy way to get it done

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex. In pre Java 8:

```
Collection<String> strings; // given this
String filter = "a";
for (Iterator<String> i = strings.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
    if (i.next().startsWith(filter))
        i.remove();
```